# I am trying to write a function for a button which can open multiple modals in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to **create** a page with multiple modals on but for each modal i am creating a button with a function attached with `onclick()` to open them.

Is there a way which I could write one function which could then open any of the modals on page depending on the container the button is in?

**Here is my example code.**

```
  <div>
      <button type="button" onclick="showModal1()">Open Modal</button>
      <div id="overlay"></div>
      <div class="modal" id="modal1">
          <span class="close" onclick="hideModal1()"></span>
          <p>modal content</p>
   </div>
   </div>

<div>
    <button type="button" onclick="showModal2()">Open Modal</button>
    <div id="overlay"></div>
    <div class="modal" id="modal2">
        <span class="close" onclick="hideModal2()"></span>
        <p>modal content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

js

```
function showModal1() {
    document.getElementById("modal1").style.display = "block",
    document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block"
}
function hideModal1() {
    document.getElementById("modal1").style.display = "none",
    document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none"
}
function showModal2() {
    document.getElementById("modal2").style.display = "block",
    document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block"
}
function hideModal2() {
    document.getElementById("modal2").style.display = "none",
    document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none"
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by container?

Comment: In your example, the buttons are not in any container. Could you extend the code a bit more, so that it more resamples what the final markup looks like? It's not useful for you if we invent some structure that's not really usable for you later.

Comment: Also, there are two div elements with the same id "overlay"

Comment: Sorry didn't really explain very well, container was just the div and the id="overlay" is just for a black background when the modal pops us. cheers

Comment: Right, but you can't have to identical ids, ids need to be unique.

Comment: Thanks for all the solutions, much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple example thet does what you asked for, using only one function. Of course, one could (and should) try to make it even more generic like thesublimeobject did in his answer, getting rid of "onclick" to separate HTML and script.

```js
function showModal(modalId) {
document.getElementById("modal" + modalId).style.display = "block",
document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block"
}
function hideModal(modalId) {
document.getElementById("modal" + modalId).style.display = "none",
document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none"
}
```

```css
.modal {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: none;
  z-index: 100;
  background: #fff;
  min-width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  }

.modal .close {
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
}

#overlay {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0.4;
  background-color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<div id="overlay"></div>

<button type="button" onclick="showModal(1)">Open Modal</button>
<div class="modal" id="modal1">
<span class="close" onclick="hideModal(1)">X</span>
<p>modal content</p>
</div>

<button type="button" onclick="showModal(2)">Open Modal</button>
<div class="modal" id="modal2">
<span class="close" onclick="hideModal(2)">X</span>
<p>modal content</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way.

```
<button type="button" onclick="showModal(1)">Open Modal</button>
<div id="overlay"></div>
<div class="modal" id="modal1">
    <span class="close" onclick="hideModal(1)"></span>
    <p>modal content</p>
</div>

<button type="button" onclick="showModal(2)">Open Modal</button>
<div id="overlay"></div>
<div class="modal" id="modal2">
    <span class="close" onclick="hideModal(2)"></span>
    <p>modal content</p>
</div>
```

js

```
function showModal(modal_no) {
    document.getElementById("modal"+modal_no).style.display = "block",
    document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block"
}
function hideModal(modal_no) {
    document.getElementById("modal"+modal_no).style.display = "none",
    document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're able to use jQuery, you can bind an event handler to the "click" JavaScript element using the [`.click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) method, and you can find nearby elements using [`.siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) and [`.parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) (among others). This way, you just need to define one binding for each of the modal opening class and the modal closing class, and use their context to determine which modal to open and close. Note that `$(this)` captures the specific element that was clicked on.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.modal-open').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('.modal').add('#overlay').show();
  });

  $('.modal-close').click(function() {
    $(this).parent('.modal').add('#overlay').hide();
  });
});
```

```css
.modal {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: none;
  z-index: 100;
  background: #fff;
  min-width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.modal-close {
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
}
#overlay {
  opacity: 0.4;
  background-color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="display:none" id="overlay"></div>

<div>
  <button class="modal-open">Open Modal #1</button>
  <div style="display:none" class="modal">
    <span class="modal-close">x</span>
    <p>Modal #1 content</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <button class="modal-open">Open Modal #2</button>
  <div style="display:none" class="modal">
    <span class="modal-close">x</span>
    <p>Modal #2 content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** In order for `.siblings('.modal')` to work correctly here, the button and modal should be placed within their own `<div>` element, or you run the risk that the button could be siblings with two elements with the `modal` class.

You could also do this with vanilla JavaScript using [`.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). You'll have to get sibling and parent elements in a different way, of course.

Answer (score 0):

First, put a class of some sort on all of your buttons; let's say `modal__trigger`. Then assign each of them some sort of dynamic data-attribute; let's say, for example,

`<button class="modal__trigger" data-modal="modal--id">Button</button>`

Now, for each modal, assign a matching ID:

`<div class="modal" id="modal--id">Content</div>`

Now, all you need to do is add listeners with whatever events you want, like open, close, etc.

```
for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', open.bind(buttons[i]))
}

function open() {
    let id = this.getAttribute('data-modal')
    let modal = document.getElementById(id)
    modal.classList.add('modal--visible')
}

function close() {
    (however you want to close the modal, using the same sort of logic)
}
```

This is an extremely simplified version that will work in a base case. I have a much more complex library written for our internal team if you would like me to link you to it, but I don't know if it's necessary at all in this case.